# Error writing from S3 to EBS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ebs

I'm trying to copy from an S3 bucket to a mounted EBS volume on a Windows EC2 Instance.

I have the following IAM policies in place:

> AmazonEC2FullAccess
>   AmazonS3FullAccess
>   AmazonElasticFileSystemFullAccess

When I try to copy to the EC2 directly everything works. (I've used the aws cli, S3Express and S3 Browser) However, if I copy to the mounted volume directly, I get a permissions error on S3 Browser (and similar errors with the other methods):

> Failed - System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path
>   'D:\test.mov_map' is denied

Any thoughts would be appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I did some digging, if you are using a pre-bundled Amazon Linux S3 bucket then you already have access. For other Linux instances, you have to manually configure access. Have you installed the CLI on S3?  If not that needs to be done first.

Second, your IAM policies are connected to IAM roles, yes?  If you use an IAM role then it should be OK.  If you are using keys/secret keys then configure CLI to use those.

Verify your access to S3 and you should be able to copy.  Here's a link that explains it step by step:  https://n2ws.com/how-to-guides/how-to-copy-data-from-s3-to-ebs.html

For more information on managing your [AWS EBS volumes](https://cloud.netapp.com/blog/managing-ebs-volumes-in-aws-cloud), you can check out this blog post from NetApp.